# add key dynamically to a php array

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic, key

I have got following array in php:

```
theArray('id':'123','akey':'a';

         'id':'234','akey':'b';

         'id':'567','akey':'c';)
```

I would like to dynamically add another key in a loop so that my array will look like:

```
theArray('id':'123','akey':'a', 'anotherkey':'1';

         'id':'234','akey':'b'; 'anotherkey':'1';

         'id':'567','akey':'c'; 'anotherkey':'1';)
```

The code I have written is the following:

```
foreach($theArray as $row)
{
  $row['anotherkey'] = "1";
}
```

but it is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not actually storing your new value in `$theArray`, you're just assigning it to your temporary `$row` variable.  What you want to do is this:

```
foreach($theArray as $key => $row) {
    $theArray[$key]["anotherkey"] = "1";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
foreach($theArray as &$row)
{
  $row['anotherkey'] = "1";
}
```

Comment: and don't forget unset $row after loop - otherwise it can call a lot of  bugs in future

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($theArray as $key => $row)
{
  $theArray[$key]['anotherkey'] = "1";
}
```

is more robust